# Enable infinite timeout Domino v.9.0.1

Tags: xpages, lotus-domino

I have a Domino server v.9.0.1. I want to increase the timeout for my web users.

I have one user that gets an error when he try to save de document. He told me that he stays many time with the document open and then he gets the error. I think that is a timeout error, but I'm not sure.

Thanks in advance,

The error appears in currentDocument.save();
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CHsYy.jpg)

Answer (score 3):

Set Xsp Properties

- Session timeout `xsp.session.timeout` and
- Application timeout `xsp.application.timeout`

to a value (in minutes) of your choice.

[image]

The session timeout is the number of minutes of user inactivity that causes the server to delete user's session data.

The application timeout is the number of minutes of all users being inactiv that causes the server to delete application's data in memory.

John Dalsgaard wrote a good [blog](http://www.dalsgaard-data.eu/blog/tuning-your-xpages/) about how to set the values.

His recommendation is to set session timeout to a short time period like 5 minutes and send regularly a "Keep session alive" from client to server and a long application timeout.

Comment: In my experience, the session stays alive using a "Keep session alive" controil, but viewScope and the document are somehow destroyed after some time. I'd love to know if this works for you.

Comment: I agree on "Keep session alive". Bear in mind that a very long scope will mean the session persists for that period of time after the browser is closed. This could affect server performance. Also, HTTP timeout is separate from xsp session timeout, so you will need to amend both.